# Custom executable cannot run shortly after boot up.

Tags: executable, yocto

Having a strange issue when running some custom executables on a Yocto distribution with the Xilinx kernel shortly after booting.

Here's a rundown of my actions:

1. Boot system
2. SSH into system once network is established
3. Run executable with invalid parameters (missing), executable hangs with no errors or logs. Closes with a Ctrl+C.
4. Wait a couple minutes and rerun the executable with invalid parameters, get a usage statement indicating the missing required parameters.

Any ideas on why this would occur / how to fix it?

Thanks.